# Tooltip using ng-bootstrap on SVG elements not showing

Tags: d3.js, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I created circle using D3.js. I used ng-bootstrap for Tooltip but It is not showing on svg element,

```
g.append("g").selectAll("circle").data(this.RecordDaily).enter().append("circle")
                               .attr("r", 5).attr("fill", "purple")
                               .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(parseTime(d.moy)); })
                               .attr("cy", function (d, i) { return y(d.session); })
                               .attr("data-toggle", "tooltip").attr("title", function (d) { return d.session })
                               .attr("ngbTooltip",  function (d) { return d.session })
                               .attr("placement",  "top")
```